# Why is the f word still allowed in profiles?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, offensive

Waffles is getting upset.

The management, with its magnificent reality distortion field, seem to have a Stalinesque attitude towards the F-word, with one notable exception: user profiles.

Sometimes, after clicking on a user's profile I am promptly presented with a nasty word. This makes me **cry**, because I did not sign up for this horrid language. I am a delicate flower waiting to bloom.

Why is the F-BOMB still allowed in user profiles?

Comment: No... Why would you do this? There's one last sanctuary where I'm allowed to be myself. Why must you draw Atwood's unyielding gaze to it? Why do you hate me so much, waffles?

Comment: Atwood has SQL and full text search ... he sees everything like the eye of mordor.

Comment: I eat Net Nanny for breakfast with my

Comment: Because you like lasers.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The user page is a reflection of that user and it is their page to do with what they will.

(Within reason, *of course*.)

We also allow explicit self-promotion on the user page, which is not allowed in posts, either.

Comment: Now that we have expanding user cards, profile content is much easier to see 'accidentally' than deliberately. I'm not saying this policy needs to change, but people that have ... interesting ... profile content might want to take steps to ensure that inappropriate language doesn't appear in the expanded info on mouseover.

Comment: Sadly "within reason" is now a rather confusing caveat, at least to many people. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336608/218334

Answer (score 26):

The language used in questions and answers reflects on the site as a whole. Language used in a profile reflects only on the owner of the profile.

Comment: We hope that is how people will see these things

Comment: @Malachi Well, all we have is hope. We can't really expect that.

Answer (score 12):

The Q&A side is for well worded Qs, and well worded As. A well worded ANYTHING doesn't need swearing. A profile describes who you as a person are, and swearing is an easy way to help define large swathes of a personality.

Comment: re: "easy way to help define large swathes of a personality" ... or, y'know, lack of same.  :)

Comment: Is part of a personality, after all :P