# One user is putting another user in the pillory on his profile page. Is it really ok?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I found a user's profile, where the user puts another (already suspended) user in the pillory in his description. It is not me, but I think this behavior is not ok.
So I flagged it, but my flag got declined

> this user puts another (already suspended) user in the pillory on his profile page. I think that is not ok. – 7 mins ago

The response was

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I think this is lynch law and should not be practiced on Stack Overflow.

So how to deal with it if moderators decline those flags?

Comment: If the mod declined the flag then they didn't feel there was a problem...without a link to the user we don't have enough information to really disagree with them.

Comment: if I post the user's link, I put him in pillory…

Comment: If you don't want to post a link, you don't *have* to, I'm just saying that, unless I'm given reason to think otherwise, I'll assume the moderator was correct in thinking that there was nothing inappropriate worth acting on.  If you want to convince me that something was wrong, you'll need to provide more information.

Comment: If you don't post it, nothing can be done about it. If someone does go on a mass downvote-question-spree the fruad filter will kick in and his rep will return to normal. He may also not see an issue with what he is doing.

Comment: Meh, it's all a bit ranty-mac-ranterson, but not offensive enough (IMHO) to warrant any action.

Comment: The person that's been "pillored" is suspended for a *year*. That's some major rule infringement to warrant that. So IMHO the user should take out the ranty stuff now that the issue has been dealt with (I guess suspened users can't vote?)

Comment: I think that the user should be asked to remove his rant, as it is up to moderators to deal with something like this — as they did. Especially since the pillored user has no means to take action because of his suspension.

Comment: Is it bad that my first instinct was to edit the profile to correct the grammar and punctuation?

Comment: wth does "pillored" / "pillory" mean?

Comment: @Sathya: "to name and shame somebody"

Comment: @vikingosegundo The general idea has always been that the profile is the only place where almost anything goes, unless incredibly offensive. See for example [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31504/rules-for-profiles) as well as [this statement by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31197/why-is-the-f-word-still-allowed-in-profiles/31209#31209).

Comment: @Bart: *The user page is a reflection of that user*. Does that really include rants?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Do you think rants reflect on that user?  I do.  Sometimes it's positive, sometimes it's not, but in both cases it is a reflection of that person.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I leave that up to the user to answer. I could give you several examples where the response would be a definite yes. :)

Comment: I sometimes wonder with people like this if there is something else negative in their life and we are all like their virtual punching bags.

Comment: ok, I think we got enough input on this topic. I will delete the link now. Thanks for every contribution.

Comment: The real question is who's handing out the rotten fruit so we can start throwing it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You deal with it by going about your life and letting go.

You can't control people, only your reaction to them.

There's nothing in the profile that's particularly offensive, and if they think ranting in their profile will help, let them rant, as long as it's not crossing boundaries. They'll learn it won't help for the same reason.

Comment: The first two sentences should really be the accepted answer to 99% of the questions asked here and in RL.

Comment: @GEOCHET Heh; that's pretty much true--and much easier to say than do. We all have our hooks.